# In what language does a method not return a value and a function does?

Tags: java, c++, functional-programming, methods

I don't know from where I got this but in my head a function returns a value and a method does not.

I know that with OOP a method is a function related to a class. But I am trying to remember where I got this idea.

Comment: There's no consistency in this area that can be relied upon. I have taken to talking about "methods" to mean anything which is callable/contains instructions - including functions, routines, subroutines, and procedures. In modern programming practice, the distinction between methods that return values, and methods that don't, is not a fundamental one (features that perhaps once distinguished them, like multiple entry points for subroutines, have been long abolished).

Comment: So you heard the bell ring but you don't know where the clapper is hanging... (if you are not Dutch, please ignore this). I suspect the source of your information stems from Pascal and you are mixing up some things. In Pascal a method that yields no result is called a **procedure** and declared as such, starting with the word `procedure`. A method that does yield a result is called a **function**, declared as such, starting with the word `function`. Methods are just behavior within an OO context and can be implemented using different constructs depending on the language.

Comment: @MartinMaat Indeed, the explicit distinction between *Procedure* and *Function* is a Pascal invention. Pascal's predecessor Algol used only the term *Procedure* regarding its definition (although the [language manual](https://www.algol60.org/reports/algol60_mr.pdf) referred to *function specifier* to mean the use of a procedure call in an expression).

Comment: Even more interestingly, Niklaus Wirth, Pascal's inventor [later](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/234286.1057812) referred to Pascal functions as   *function procedures*, and claimed it needed improvement. And surprise, he didn't keep the explicit syntactic difference in [Modula2](http://parallel.vub.ac.be/education/modula2/documentation/quickreference-advanced.html), the language he designed as Pascal's direct successor, and  which defines functions as a procedures.

Answer (score 7):

**[Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)#Procedures_and_functions)** introduced this difference between a **`procedure`**, which can be called in a statement but does not return a value, and a **`function`**, which can be called in an expression to return a value. Descendents of Pascal, most notably **[Ada](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/Ada_For_The_CPP_Java_Developer/chapters/06_Functions_and_Procedures.html)** continue to promote this difference.
Previous structured languages such as Algol and Simula did not make the distinction and used only the `procedure`.

**Methods** are orthogonal to the question of returning a value or not. Methods is the term used to qualify functions and procedures that are invoked on an object or a class. Its origin is  [Smalltalk](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/512760.512762), that defined methods as the way to define how objects respond to messages received from other objects, as does James Gosling, the inventor of Java in his [foundational white paper](https://www.stroustrup.com/1995_Java_whitepaper.pdf) in 1995 (page 37).

Note that these terms are heavily influenced by the language context. For example, Ada uses `procedure` and `function` also for the definition of methods, and C++ calls them all functions (member or not of a class), whereas UML uses the term “operation”. But if you know what you mean and disambiguate for your readers, there will be no issues ;-)

Comment: PL/SQL in Oracle makes the same distinction, too. A procedure has no return value (but may contain `out` parameters) and a function must return a value (it cannot be a "void" return-type).

Comment: @GregBurghardt very interesting! And logical: the designers of [PL/SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/SQL#cite_note-2) modelled the language on the base of Ada, which makes it one of the Pascal descendants as well ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Some people assign specific meanings to words like *function*, *procedure*, *subroutine*, *method*. However, these meanings are not really universal. I don't find it very helpful to use these terms unless I define what specifically I mean by those words.

Often, languages pick *one* word for all of these concepts.
In Java, all of these concepts are referred to as “methods”.
In C, it's called a “function” even if it returns void.
In Perl, the language construct is called a “subroutine” but some subroutines are used as methods.

If someone makes a distinction between these concepts, typical meanings are:

- A **function** returns a value, similar to the concept of a [mathematical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) that maps its input to a (single) output value. Some people insist that true functions are pure, i.e. their output depends solely on on the input parameters and there are no side effects.
- A **procedure** does not return a value. The terms **routine**, **subroutine**, or **subprogram** are equivalent but are typically associated with low-level unstructured programming (e.g. assembly). The procedure communicates with other parts of the program through global variables or out-parameters. In low-level programming, a subroutine might have multiple entry points and might not return to the caller. In some languages, procedures/subprograms cannot be recursive.
- A **method** belongs to an object/instance, but may otherwise be function-like or procedure-like. In its strictest sense, the word only applies to dynamically dispatched (virtual) instance methods, but in practice it is also used for other instance methods and even for other class members such as “static” methods.